# Removing occluded segmentations

Tags: opencv

I have a segmented image and an original image. I want to be able to draw bounding boxes on objects in actual image using the segmentations. So far using cv2.findContours(), and cv2.Canny() are both able to find bboxes. But I want to remove objects that are hidden underneath trees or other objects as the segmentations are still there of those objects. Is there a way to discard occluded objects ?

Comment: Please share a sample image and explain

Comment: Sorry the images are propriety so not allowed to share. But imagine a car behind a tree and in the segmentation the mask of the car will be incomplete (since half of it is occluded behind tree leaves). Is there a way in OPENCV to ignore such segmentations.

Comment: Using OpenCV it isn't possible. But there are deep learning networks that can accurately guess the shape of an occluded object